# Angular routing to proper page and to proper element

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have the main structure in app component.

```
<body>
<header></header>
<nav class="navbar">
  <app-nav></app-nav>
</nav>
<section>
</section>
<aside></aside>
<footer></footer>
</body>
```

The about compotent includes the html page.

```
<article>
  about works!
</article>
```

I use routing to put html page from about compotent into section element in app compotent.
In app.module.

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'about',
        component: AboutComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
```

Links in app-nav compotent html page.

```
    <ul class="topnav">
      <li *ngFor="let menuItem of menuItems; let index = index">
        <a [class.active]="index == 0" routerLink="{{ menuItem.link }}">{{ menuItem.name }}</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Routing works good, but it puts acricle element behind ul element in app-nav component. What should I do to change it to put it into section element?